# Flutter interactive Text() rerender on text change

Tags: android, dart, flutter, state

I have a TextField, and when I am in OnChange(), I'd like to set the state of a variable to a different value. Upon setting this value, I'd like to re=render the value of the Text(). Does Flutter not re-render widgets on state changes? I assume flutter behaved similarly to react, but that doesn't appear to be the case, at least in a straight forward manner. For example, I'd like to change the contents of the Text, ideally to the value that's entered in the text field. Am I missing something? I've tried looking through the docs, and haven't found anything meaningful in terms of what I'm trying to do.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wedding_app/models/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:wedding_app/models/state/budget/budget.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class BudgetPage extends BudgetState {
  String totalBudget;
  final formatCurrency = new NumberFormat.simpleCurrency();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return budgetForm(context);
  }

  Widget budgetForm(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: _widgets(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _widgets(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .05),
        color: ApplicationColors.ivory,
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                ),
                Text(
                  totalBudget == "123" ? "123" : "Total Budget", // rerender this on state change of total budget
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "acme",
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: ApplicationColors.black),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                ),
                TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter your budget",
                      labelText: "Total Budget",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "acme")),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      totalBudget = formatCurrency.format(value);
                      // tried printing value here with print(totalBudget), but doesn't print to console for some reason. This is where I want to set the state
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Stateful Widgets can't be written  in a single class. At least not this way. Otherwise you'll loose their state randomly

Comment: Sorry, my state is actually separated out in a other file, see the state import on line 3